# Cannot Upgrade to Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, release-upgrade

As you know, Kubuntu 12.04 came out recently. Since I want to upgrade from 11.10, I followed the instructions on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/Kubuntu). However, after completing the update all packages step and rebooting, I never got a notification letting me upgrade to 12.04. I have tried the update again many times, and I have rebooted after each upgrade, yet I have never gotten this notification.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open sofware sources. click on Updates tab and then in release upgrade select Normal release release

[image]

Thrn enter this into terminal and see what you get
`sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f kde -d`

Comment: I tried it, and it checked for a new version of Ubuntu, but it couldn't find any. I suppose that explains why the upgrade notification wasn't appearing. I've checked my software sources and found [this](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/9326/softwaresources2942012.jpg), but I'm not sure if anything's missing or should be checked...

Comment: if this has solved your problem plz mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you don't need the -d on do-release-upgrade, because Precise is no longer a development version.

From the terminal, `sudo do-release-upgrade` should be sufficient.